# Animate grid of layers radially from a point

Tags: algorithm, math, grid, cartesian-coordinates

So I'm trying to find an algorithm for animating a grid radially from a chosen cell.

For example, let's say I have the following grid and the cell with the "o" is the chosen one to start from:

```
x | x | x | x | x | 
x | x | x | x | x | 
x | x | x | o | x | 
x | x | x | x | x | 
x | x | x | x | x |
```

and this should continue to go on this way:

```
x | x | x | x | x | 
x | x | x | o | x | 
x | x | o | o | o | 
x | x | x | o | x | 
x | x | x | x | x |

x | x | x | o | x | 
x | x | o | o | o | 
x | o | o | o | o | 
x | x | o | o | o | 
x | x | x | o | x |

x | x | o | o | o | 
x | o | o | o | o | 
o | o | o | o | o | 
x | o | o | o | o | 
x | x | o | o | o |
```

etc. So I basically need to loop through and every time I do so, I need the coordinates for the new cells that need to be switched in cartesian coordinates (ie x,y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following python-like pseudocode will accomplish this, although it will switch some cells multiple times. So let `switch` be only from `x` to `o`, without effect on cells which already are in state `o`.

```py
for i in 0 .. size: # iteration
  for j in 0 .. i: # both end points are inclusive
    switch(x - i + j, y + j)
    switch(x - i + j, y - j)
    switch(x + i - j, y + j)
    switch(x + i - j, y - j)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply run over the grid (this portion of code can be optimized) and change `x` to `y` if it has adjacent `o`'s. Then run again and change all `y`'s to `o`'s.

Another solution will be to save initial `o` location (x0, y0) and change all `x` to `o` if `abs(x - x0) + abs(y - y0) = i` on `i`th iteration.